Find Matrix Describing The 2D Ellipse Made by Intersecting a 3D Ellipsoid w/ a Plane
I have a covariance matrix (P) describing an ellipsoid as well as an observer. The ellipsoid is centered at the origin and the observer is far away. I am fairly certain that from the observers perspective the ellipsoid is an ellipse and it is the outer perimeter made by projecting the ellipsoid onto a plane perpendicular to the line connecting the observer to the center of the ellipse.
In equations I have a semi-positive definite matrix P. Let L be a 3x3 matrix whose diagonal elements are the eigen values of P and v be a 3x3 matrix whose columns are the eigen vectors of P. The ellipsoid is then described by x^T A x = 1 with A = v^T L^-1 v. If I project this onto the plane using T (a simple 2x3 transform matrix) it produces a 2d ellipse of the form m^T B m = 1 where m are 2d vectors in the orthonormal basis of the plane. I want the matrix B.
An equivalent way I attempted to solve the problem geometrically is to find the 1D line characterized by the intersection of the ellipsoid and the plane. If I can parameterize it I can take the derivative and find the max/min of that in terms of distance from the line. Those points then define the major and minor axis of the projected ellipse and I'm set. Once I find the major point I can find the minor analytically since there's only one line perpendicular to the line of sight and the major axis and that line is easy to parameterize. But I can't find a way to parameterize the 2D ellipse in that plane itself.
A third equivalent question, which may be the simplest. I have a 3D ellipsoid and a line through the center. What are the two points (really 4 because symmetry) that are the farthest/closest to that line.
Any help on this would be appreciated as I'm really stuck finding the farthest point on the ellipsoid from the line analytically. I wrote a quick gradient descent solver but that's it.
For context, if it helps, I have a covariance describing the position uncertainty of an object. I want the covariance describing that uncertainty to an observer looking at the object. So a 2D covariance in az/el of the observer or in distance units in the focal plane of the observer. I can move between the two easily.

What does "the observer is far away mean"? Is it at infinity or is it at a specific location described by your matrix? Also, could you provide a small example of a covariance matrix and explain how it can describe your problem?

You could consider a rotation carriyng the plane to the $z=0$ plane. The image of the ellipsoid at $z=0$ would then give you the equation of the ellipse.

See a past answer of mine here to a question having a large similarity with yours.

@JoanS.GuillametF. The observer is far away but at a finite distance. I probably should have dropped the far away part of the post but I had already used the small angle approximation to get the angular size of the ellipsoid to the observer so it was in my mind.

@JeanMarie That is very helpful. Another pointer to the Schur compliment, along with the detailed answer posted. That was what I was missing. Thank you!
